# Entity Framework - Code First - TPH and WillCascadeOnDelete(true)

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first, entity-relationship

I have an issue when using TPH and `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`. When I have the value set on true for cascade on delete my database is not created. The exception message is the following one:

> *Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.MembersProfiles_dbo.Contacts_ContactId' on table 'MembersProfiles' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.*

In order to clear things out here is my model and the mapping used for it.

```
public class MemberProfile
{
   public Guid MemberProfileId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Contact
{
   public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
   public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class PersonContact : Contact
{
     public string Profession { get; set; }
     public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationContact : Contact
{
     public string SalesPhone { get; set; }
     public string ServicePhone { get; set; }
}

public class ContactMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
    {
        public ContactMap()
        {
            ToTable("Contacts");
            HasKey(c => c.ContactId);

            Property(c => c.ContactId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(c => c.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);
            Property(c => c.MobilePhone).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(15);
            Property(c => c.Description).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(500);
            Property(c => c.FixPhone).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(15);
            Property(c => c.FaxNumber).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(15);

            HasRequired(mp => mp.Address).WithMany().HasForeignKey(mp => mp.AddressId);
            HasRequired(mp => mp.Link).WithMany().HasForeignKey(mp => mp.LinkId);
            HasRequired(mp => mp.Image).WithMany().HasForeignKey(mp => mp.MediaId);
        }
    }

 public class PersonContactMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PersonContact>
 {
        public PersonContactMap()
        {
            Property(pc => pc.Profession).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(150);
            Property(pc => pc.OrganizationName).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(150);

            Map(pc => pc.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("PersonContact").HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));                }
    }

public class OrganizationContactMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrganizationContact>
{
        public OrganizationContactMap()
        {
            Property(oc => oc.SalesPhone).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(15);
            Property(oc => oc.ServicePhone).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(15);

            Map(oc => oc.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("OrganizationContact").HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));
        }
}

public class MemberProfileMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MemberProfile>
{
        public MemberProfileMap()
        {
            ToTable("MembersProfiles");
            HasKey(mp => mp.MemberProfileId);

            Property(mp => mp.MemberProfileId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(mp => mp.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(mp => mp.DateOfBirth).IsRequired();
            Property(mp => mp.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);
            Property(mp => mp.MobilePhone).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(15);
            Property(mp => mp.Summary).IsOptional();

            HasRequired(mp => mp.Address).WithMany().HasForeignKey(mp => mp.AddressId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            Property(mp => mp.AddressId).HasColumnName("AddressId");

            HasOptional(mp => mp.Media).WithMany().Map(mp => mp.MapKey(new[] { "MediaId" })).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            HasOptional(mp => mp.Tags).WithMany().Map(mp => mp.MapKey(new[] { "TagId" })).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            HasOptional(mp => mp.Contacts).WithMany().Map(mp => mp.MapKey(new[] { "ContactId" })).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
}
```

Unfortunately I am not able to realize what am I doing wrong... so any clue would be much appreciated.

P.S: I am using EF 5.0 Code First

Answer (score 1):

See if this [BlogPost helps.](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx), another option i would try to start adding relation one by one to see where it breaks rather than stacking everything at once. And sometimes it helps to just use `individual property mappings` rather than `Fluent API` like you have done. Check out different links on that blog i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the issue. I have two tables referring addresses table. In my case both Contacts and MemberProfile hold a reference to Addresses table and in both cases the cascade delete was turned on. Once I turned off the cascade delete on one of the relations everything worked just fine.